# Why from utils impost fs_data_dir doesn't work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, debugging, package, google-colaboratory

I'm studying about the searchline analysis from [BrainIAK](https://brainiak.org/tutorials/07-searchlight/). But the code

```
from utils import fs_data_dir, results_path

print('data dir = %s' % (fs_data_dir))
```

I ran it on google colab but it doesn't work.

I've searched for the utils package in python but I didn't find anything about fs_data_dir!

I have a project that depends on running this code. So I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `utils.py` is from

https://github.com/brainiak/brainiak-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/utils.py

So, you can get it with

!wget https://github.com/brainiak/brainiak-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/utils.py

Then you can use `from utils import fs_data_dir, results_path`